# Beautiful Soup class name has multiple space and find_all is giving []

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Using beautiful soup I was trying to extract the value (317.69) but getting empty result. The html code block which i tried to extract is:

```
<span class="Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(ib)">317.69</span>
```

I tried with the following 2 ways to code:

```
value = soup.find_all(attrs={'class': 'Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(ib)'})
```

and

```
value = soup.find_all('span', class_='Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(ib)')
```

But getting result `[]` if i use `print(value.text)`

Note: the XPath of that `//span[@class="Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(ib)"]` is successfully pointing the correct element. But for beautiful soup the output is empty using python.

I tried first the appraoch of beautiful soup website form the documentaion:

[image]

But no luck :(

Can anybody suggest me the correct way to extract value from there? i mean if there is multiple classes how to extract the value

Code I tried:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL?p=AAPL'

response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
p = soup.find_all(attrs={'class': 'Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(ib)'})
print(p)
```

Comment: You have a typo in `... attrs={'class': 'aTrsdu(0.3s)'...`.  Ensure that your statement is `soup.find_all(attrs={'class': 'Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(ib)'})`. The second option using `class_` may not actually work reliably.

Comment: that was a type when i typed. I fixed from the post. But stil it is not working. full code I tried is: import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL?p=AAPL'

response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
p = soup.find_all(attrs={'class': 'Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(ib)'})
print(p)

Comment: If you create the soup using just that tag that you had in your question, I can tell you that it works - that's what I used to test your question out.  You also need to realise that these classes are automatically generated using the react framework that this site uses and they are not stable at all, so they are not suitable for repeat extraction of data.

Comment: what will be the best approach to parse such type of site (react site) ?

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
from simplified_scrapy.simplified_doc import SimplifiedDoc
html ='''
<span class="Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(ib)">317.69</span>
'''
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
eles = doc.getElementsByClass('Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(ib)')
print ([ele.text for ele in eles])
# Get the first
ele = doc.getElementByClass('Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(ib)')
print (ele.text)
```

Result:

```
['317.69']
317.69
```

Comment: That is okay. But my target is to do using BeautifulSoup. Any thoughts about using BeautifulSoup to solve that issue?